# GatsbyImage is not working when querying images from the Gallery ACF from WordPress

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the gallery ACF in WordPress, my console.log proves my query and component to be accurately sourcing the data, however, the gallery images do not show up on my page both locally or in a production build. Can someone please help me figure this out?

**My query:**

```
query GalleryQuery {
    wpPage(databaseId: {eq: 41}) {
      ACF_GalleryPage {
        gallery {
          id
          altText
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
              fluid {
                base64
                tracedSVG
                srcWebp
                srcSetWebp
                originalImg
                originalName
                src
              }
              fixed {
                src
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**My component:**

```
export default function GalleryPortfolio() {
  const data = useGalleryQuery()
  return (
    <Section>
      <Container>
        {data.wpPage.ACF_GalleryPage.gallery.map(localFile => {
          console.log(localFile.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid.src);
          <GatsbyImage image={localFile.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid.src} alt="" />
          
       })}
      </Container>
    </Section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) (from Gatsby 1 and 2) and [`gatsby-plugin-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image) (from Gatsby 3 onwards). More specifically, you are running a `gatsby-image` query (that has `fluid` or `fixed` properties) and using a `gatsby-plugin-image` component (`GatsbyImage`) which only accepts an `image` property, not `fixed` or `fluid`.

That said, remove the `gatsby-image` references and check the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/) to ensure that you are using the proper configuration. In the end, you need to have something like this in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

This configuration will create the proper nodes when fetching your ACF images, not `fluid` or `fixed` as it right now.

Because you have already a `gatsbyImageData` node, it seems that you have both plugins running and creating their own nodes so once you get rid of `gatsby-image` the query should simply look like:

```
query GalleryQuery {
    wpPage(databaseId: {eq: 41}) {
      ACF_GalleryPage {
        gallery {
          id
          altText
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you simply need to pass the `gatsbyImageData` as `image`:

```
export default function GalleryPortfolio() {
  const data = useGalleryQuery()
  return (
    <Section>
      <Container>
        {data.wpPage.ACF_GalleryPage.gallery.map(localFile => {
          console.log(localFile.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid.src);
          <GatsbyImage image={localFile.localFile.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt="" />
          
       })}
      </Container>
    </Section>
  )
}
```